# Merge Sort index error

Tags: java, mergesort

I have two arrays, one string and one int, I want to order the arrays by the int array, all while the string array has to correspond with the int array, so if I move one int I need to move a string, or vice verca. the way I have it now I get exception out of bounds.

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] arr,String[] str) {
    if (arr.length > 1 && str.length > 1) {
        int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, arr.length/2);
        int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, left.length, arr.length);
        String[] Sl = Arrays.copyOfRange(str, 0, str.length/2);
        String[] Sr = Arrays.copyOfRange(str, Sl.length, str.length);

        mergeSort(right, Sr);
        mergeSort(left, Sl);
        merge(right, left, Sr, Sl,arr, str);
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] left, int[] right,
                         String[] Sleft, String[] Sright,
                         int[] orig, String[] sorig) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int tots = right.length + left.length;
    while (f < tots) {
        if (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
            if (left[i] < right[j]) {
                orig[f] = left[i];
                sorig[f] = Sleft[i];
                i++;
                f++;
            } else if(left[i] > right[j]) {
                orig[f] = right[j];
                sorig[f] = Sright[j];
                j++;
                f++;
            }
        } else if (i >= left.length) {
            orig[f] = left[i];
            sorig[f] = Sleft[i];
            f++;
            j++;
        } else if (j >= left.length) {
            orig[f] = right[j];
            sorig[f] = Sright[j];
            f++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have some arrays with example values in them, and perhaps even a fully working class, with a main function, so we don't have to create them ourselves. *Trying out* your code is way better than just *looking* at it...

Comment: change copyOfRange(arr, left.length, arr.length); to copyOfRange(arr, left.length-1, arr.length); and String[] Sr = Arrays.copyOfRange(str, Sl.length, str.length); to String[] Sr = Arrays.copyOfRange(str, Sl.length-1, str.length);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
} else if (i >= left.length) {
    orig[f] = left[i];
```

as this point, `i` will always be out of bounds, because you are specifically testing if it is just the line before.